# How can I have onclick functionality for my CollectionView cells?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, uicollectionview

I want to make it so that when I tap on a CollectionView Cell, it segues to another view. I also want to pass a user ID to this view so I can query the database. This is what I have implemented so far:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        let cell = collectionview.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "userCell", for: indexPath) as! UserCell

        print(user[indexPath.row].imagePath!)


        cell.userImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: user[indexPath.row].imagePath!))

        cell.nameLabel.text = user[indexPath.row].username
        cell.userID = user[indexPath.row].userID

        let destinationVC = ProfileViewController()
        destinationVC.sentUserID = user[indexPath.row].userID!

        // Let's assume that the segue name is called playerSegue
        // This will perform the segue and pre-load the variable for you to use
        //destinationVC.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toProfileFromSearch", sender: self)


        cell.addButtonTapAction = {
            // implement your logic here, e.g. call preformSegue()
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toProfileFromSearch", sender: self)
        }
        //cell.userImage.downloadImage(from: self.user[indexPath.row].imagePath!)
        //checkFollowing(indexPath: indexPath)


        return cell
    }
```

This is in the individual creation of each cell. When I click the user profile in the search area, nothing happens.

I followed other stack overflow questions to get this far. Can anyone make a complete solution for other people that need this too?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `didSelectItemAt` function, check this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let VC1 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IDYOURVIEW") as! ProfileViewController
    VC1.sentUserID = user[indexPath.row].userID!
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC1, animated: true)
}
```

If you're using segues

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toProfileFromSearch", sender: user[indexPath.row].userID!)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if segue.identifier == "toProfileFromSearch"
    {
      let vc = segue.destination as? ProfileViewController
      if let id = sender as! String
      {
          vc?.sentUserID = id
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need both of those implementations? I'm trying the didSelectItemAt and it's not registering my click. I put a print statement in there to see if it was just the segue not working, but the print statement never prints.

Comment: not, you need to choose one, I suggest you the second way, but first in your cellForRowAt function, delete from this line `let destinationVC` to `cell.addButtonTapAction`

Answer (score 0):

There is another better way to handle this using `protocol`

```swift
protocol UserCellTapedDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didTapButton(_ cell: UserCell, didSelectItemAt id: Int)
}
```

then your cell would be like:

```swift
class UserCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    public var userID: Int!
    public weak var delegate: UserCellTapedDelegate?
    
    @objc private func addButtonTapAction() {
        delegate?.didTapButton(self, didSelectItemAt: userID)
    }
}
```

`userID`: to store the user ID.

`delegate`: use an optional weak (in terms of memory management) delegate reference in your cell.

`addButtonTapAction` func to handle target of the button/or tap gesture on Any UIView.

---

The next step is to go back to your UIViewController and conform to the custom delegate:

```swift
extension ViewController: UserCellTapedDelegate  {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionview.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "userCell", for: indexPath) as! UserCell
        ...

        cell.userID = user[indexPath.row].userID!
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
     }

    func didTapButton(_ cell: UserCell, didSelectItemAt id: Int) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toProfileFromSearch", sender: id)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "toProfileFromSearch" {
            let vc = segue.destination as! ProfileViewController
            if let id = sender as! String {
                vc.sentUserID = id
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you